# Missing javaCompileTask for variant

Tags: android, gradle, variant

Trying to build something with Android Studio 3.0 that worked fine in a previous version. Now I am seeing:

Error:Execution failed for task ':mobile-app:transformClassesWithRetrolambdaForDevDebug'.

> Missing javaCompileTask for variant: dev/debug/0 from output dir: /Users/myname/mycompany-android-app/MyProject/mobile-app/build/intermediates/transforms/retrolambda/dev/debug/0

I had a prior compile issue I got around by the adding the following to my module level build.gradle inside of defaultConfig:

javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath false
            }
        }

I can't find much of anything on "javaCompileTask". Maybe that relates to something else?

Answer (score 8):

I ended up commenting out the apply plugin for the retro lambda and that did it.

Answer (score 6):

I tried to use retrolambda version 3.6.1 with Android Gradle plugin 3.0.0-alpha5 and it does works.
This is an issue with Android Gradle plugin 3.0.0-alpha* version.

Reference:

> Does not currently work with the Retrolambda plugin. However, you should instead use the plugin's built-in support for Java 8 language features.

Documented in the `Known Issues` section at https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin.html

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem and refer to library https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda

I'm just add below line to `dependencies`

```
classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.7.0'
```

And remove this

```
plugins {
     id "me.tatarka.retrolambda" version "3.7.0"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

search **me.tatarka.retrolambda** everywhere or its subarray and comment it in 2 files named build.gradle.
this error was due to that you have install the  update in gradle
you will be able to run your android app.